# Is "Compton scattering of a photon and an electron" redundant?

Tags: scattering

My book mentions "When a photon and a free electron undergo Compton scattering..."

But isn't this redundant. Isn't Compton scattering the *name* given to the scattering of a photon and a free electron?

Can a photon and a free electron interact in a non-Compton scattering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it's useful to distinguish between Compton scattering (where the photon imparts energy to the electron) and inverse Compton scattering (where the electron imparts energy to the photon).  Beyond that, "when a photon and free electron interact ..." could plausibly refer to bremsstrahlung.

Although it's implied by the fact that the sentence refers to a photon, it is also sometimes reasonable to distinguish Compton scattering from Thompson scattering, which is the analogous effect in classical electromagnetism.

In any case, depending on context, the clause you quote ranges from "not redundant" to "mildly redundant," and therefore falls under the heading of "perfectly reasonable things to say" in my opinion.